# Настойка web-сервера Apache

Tags: apache, apache2

Нужно, чтобы все запросы к Apache вида http://myserver.ru/image/x/y, где x и y – любые целые числа, обрабатывались  скриптом resize.php, причём первое число в адресе попадало в скрипт как GET-параметр width, а второе как height. Какую настройку в Apache нужно для этого сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавить правило для .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ /resize.php?width=$1&height=$2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!